# Function for user to select between input modes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, speech-recognition

I am trying to make a assistant sort of thing in python, so basically what I want is that it asks the user to select between two INPUT modes i.e. text or Speech Input.

But the problem is that **I am not able to implement it** into the main code. Below is the sample code I tried making :

```
import keyboard
import speech_recognition as sr



def takecommandti():
    print(" ")
    rt=input(">>")
    return rt.lower()

def takeCommandsi():     
        print("Listening....")
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        r.dynamic_energy_threshold=False
        r.energy_threshold=4000
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = r.listen(source)
            said=""
        try:
            print("Recognizing....")
            said = r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
            print(f"You Said : {said}\n")
        except sr.UnknownValueError :
            print("could not understand audio \n ~Trying Again~")
            return takeCommandsi()
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Could not request results, check your internet connection; {0}".format(e))
            return "None"
        return said.lower()


input_mode_selection_variable = 0
print("Please Select in which input Mode you want to Use :) ")
print("1.Press 't' for Text Input Mode \n2.Press 's' for Speech Input Mode ")

while True :
    if keyboard.is_pressed('t'):
        print('You have successfully Selected : Text Input Mode')
        input_mode_selection_variable=False
        break
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
        print('You have successfully Selected : Speech Input Mode')
        input_mode_selection_variable=True
        break
    
def takecommand():
    if input_mode_selection_variable == False:
        takecommandti()
    elif input_mode_selection_variable ==True:
        takeCommandsi()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I finally changed some logic in the code and now it works fine for me.

here's what code i have been using now:

```
import time
import keyboard
from rich import print


def mode_select():
    print("Please Select in wich input Mode you want to Use :) ")
    print("1.Press 't' for Text Input Mode\n2.Press 's' for Speech Input Mode ")

    while True : 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('t'):
            print('You have successfully Selected : Text Input Mode')
            mode_var= 0
            time.sleep(2)
            break
        elif keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
            print('You have successfully Selected : Speech Input Mode')
            mode_var= 1
            time.sleep(2)
            break           
    return mode_var

#sample how it will be used for selecting modes : 
a=mode_select()
if a==0:
    #takecommandti()
    print("things realted to text input happen in main script :)")
elif a==1:
    #takecommandsi()    
    print("things realted to speech_input happen in main script :)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think input_mode_selection_variable will work when you Use the takecommand() function in some other Script.

Comment: "I don't think" doesn't really provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) it. If you're interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.